# Netlogo: soldiers(turtle) have a variable and i want half of them to be part of x and other half part of y

Tags: netlogo

Im creating a netlogo model that has two types of turtles, a soldier and a general. Inside the model i am creating two armies and each army consists of both soldiers and generals. Each soldier and each general belong to a army( 1 or 2). I have a slider for the number of soldiers and the number of generals. How can i put make 50% soldiers be part of army 1 and 50% soldiers part of army2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One straightforward way would be:

```
breed [ soldiers soldier ]
soldiers-own [ army ]
breed [ generals general ]
generals-own [ army ]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-soldiers number-of-soldiers [ set army 1 ]
  ask n-of (count soldiers / 2) soldiers [ set army 2 ]
  create-generals number-of-generals [ set army 1 ]
  ask n-of (count generals / 2) generals [ set army 2 ]
end
```

Another way would be to have a `number-of-soldiers-per-army` slider and then do something like:

```
create-soldiers number-of-soldiers-per-army [ set army 1 ]
create-soldiers number-of-soldiers-per-army [ set army 2 ]
```

...and the same thing for generals.

If you don't need to number of soldiers in each army to be exactly the same for each simulation run, you could go with something like that instead:

```
create-soldiers number-of-soldiers [ set army one-of [1 2] ]
```